# would the three answers of this integral $\int \frac{1}{a x^2+b x+c} d x$ make a continuous function

Tags: integration, continuity, quadratics, discriminant

so this integral $$
\int \frac{1}{a x^2+b x+c} d x
$$
has three answers depending on the discriminant $$b^2-4 a c$$ whether is positive zero or negative

1. $b^2-4 a c=0$
   $$
   \frac{-2}{2 a x+b}
   $$
2. $b^2-4 a c>0$
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}} \ln \left|\frac{2 a x+b-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a x+b+\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}\right|
   $$
3. $b^2-4 a c<0$
   $$
   \frac{2}{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 a x+b}{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}}\right)
   $$

so would a function like $$
\begin{aligned}
&-\frac{2}{2 a x+b}\left\{b^2-4 a c=0\right\}\\
&\frac{\ln \left(\left|\frac{2 a x+b-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a x+b+\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}\right|\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}\left\{b^2-4 a c>0\right\}\\
&\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 a x+b}{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}}\left\{b^2-4 a c<0\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
be continuous

Comment: Are you treating $a, b, c$ as variables?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have 3 different functions you integrate, at what point x0 and x1 will you put them together? the function you integrate are different, so why should the integrals fit at some places. Just chose a,b,c  according and plot the 3 functions.

Comment: Are you asking whether (where $y=2ax+b$ and $d = b^2 - 4ac$) $$\lim_{d\to 0+}\frac 1d\ln\left|\frac{y-d}{y+d}\right| =\lim_{d\to 0-}\frac 2d\tan^{-1}\frac yd = \frac{-2}y\ ?$$The answer is no. The inverse tangent limit diverges to $\infty$.